# Django views.py, I want to render all the attributes of a ManyToManyField from my object

Tags: python, django

At the moment, I am rendering a list of country in a select box, in order to have a category to sort my articles.

Each article has a region, defined like this in my model :

```
class Article(ModelMeta, TranslatableModel):
  regions = models.ManyToManyField(Country, verbose_name=_('Country of the article'),
                                 blank=True, null=True,
                                 related_name='regions_press_article')
```

Country is an external plugin.

But the problem is, since it's a category I want to have the country distinct and here is what I do in my views.py :

```
        region_for_articles = Article.objects.values_list('regions__pk',
                                                flat=True).distinct()
        context['regions_list'] = region_for_articles
```

In my DB, an article_region has only the ID of the region and with this ID, it find the corresponding name (requested with the value list, `region__name`).

So, it's obvious that, by doing it when I render in my template

```
{% for region in regions_list %}
  {{ region }}
{% endfor %}
```

I have only the region name accessible.

And here is my problem, I also need the slug.
But I don't figure out how to request it from my view !

How to obtain an exploitable object for my template, object that has to correspond to what is in DB for each article (you don't want to filter articles by a region which no article is link to) that will permit me to have the slug + name.

If any one has a clue for me to look at, I would be thankful :)

Comment: Why don't you just access the region directly? `{% for region in article.regions %} {{ region.name }} {{ region.slug }}`

Comment: Because if I do it, in my select there will be several time the same region.

For example, I have 3 articles with region "United Kingdom" I don't want "United Kingdom" to repeat itself 3 times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, unless you have a very good need for optimisation, you should always pass the full model objects to the template.

My rule of thumb is always to start from the model you want: since you want regions, start from the model that defines them (strangely called Country). You're after all the regions that are associated with an article, so just query for that:

```
 region_for_articles = Country.objects.exclude(regions_press_article=None)
```

Comment: Well done mate ! I will remember it, many thanks !
Just a quick question, if I want this list to be sorted alphabetically, exclude still working, right ?

Comment: Sure, just add `.order_by('slug')` or whatever.